# TypeError: (0 , import_jsx_dev_runtime.jsxDEV) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, remix.run

I am testing s remix.run app to see how it works.

I created a posts page inside `routes` directory

```
const Posts = () => {
  
  return (
    <main>
     testing
    </main>
  );
};
```

I get this error on console:

```
TypeError: (0 , import_jsx_dev_runtime.jsxDEV) is not a function 2ms
    at /home/Documents/remix/my-remix-app/app/entry.server.jsx:82:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at handleBrowserRequest (/home/Documents/remix/my-remix-app/app/entry.server.jsx:78:10)
    at handleRequest (/home/Documents/remix/my-remix-app/app/entry.server.jsx:23:7)
    at handleDocumentRequestRR (/home/Documents/remix/my-remix-app/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/server.js:260:20)
    at requestHandler (/home/Documents/remix/my-remix-app/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/server.js:49:18)
    at /home/Documents/remix/my-remix-app/node_modules/@remix-run/express/dist/server.js:39:22
```

On browser I see

```
 Unexpected Server Error
```

Comment: did you found the solution for this issue? @Yilmaz

Comment: @Dolphin no, sorry. I was just practicing remix and got this error. I was not building any app

Answer (score 2):

This is an active [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/4081) on the official remix repository. A few fixes suggested by users:

1. Adding `remix build` to `dev` script in `package.json`:

```json
"dev": "remix build && run-p dev:*"
```

2. Forcefully bumping `esbuild` version to `^0.15.8`.
3. Reverting `@remix-run/dev` to `1.6.8`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `build` and `public/build` catalogs to your `.dockerignore` file, as stated here https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/4081#issuecomment-1490389381